# Excel formula not working as conditional formatting formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The formula `=(MONTH(INDEX(Schedule, MATCH(D1, Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]], 0), 7)) = MONTH( DATEVALUE( D$2 & "1" ) )) * (YEAR(INDEX(Schedule, MATCH(D1, Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]], 0), 7)) = $B$3) * (INDEX(Schedule, MATCH(D1, Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]], 0), 7)<> "")` works fine in a cell but when I try to use it for conditional formatting I get the error "There is a problem with this formula".

My goal is to format the cells if all of the following three statements are true:

- `MONTH(INDEX(Schedule, MATCH(D1, Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]], 0), 7)) = MONTH(DATEVALUE(D$2&"1"))`
- `YEAR(INDEX(Schedule, MATCH(D1, Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]], 0), 7)) = $B$3`
- `INDEX(Schedule, MATCH(D1, Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]], 0), 7) <> ""`

I have tried using `AND()` and I've tried normal references instead of named ranges. Is there a reason why it would work in a cell but not in the conditional formatting menu? Thanks!

P.S. I am on the office insider beta channel

EDIT: Solved by @ScottCraner. I used `INDIRECT()` on all the named references and it worked. This is the final product: `=(MONTH(INDEX(INDIRECT("Schedule"), MATCH(D1, INDIRECT("Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]]"), 0), 7)) = MONTH( DATEVALUE( D$2 & "1" ) )) * (YEAR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Schedule"), MATCH(D1, INDIRECT("Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]]"), 0), 7)) = $B$3) * (INDEX(INDIRECT("Schedule"), MATCH(D1, INDIRECT("Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]]"), 0), 7)<> "")`

Comment: conditional formatting does not like structured ref, you will need to use INDIRECT().  See: https://superuser.com/questions/1517823/how-can-i-use-conditional-formatting-in-an-excel-table-using-structured-referenc  But also I believe the max length of the string is 255 which with the addition of all the INDIRECTs this formula may exceed.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That solved it

Comment: Andrew. Instead of mentioning the solution in the question, you can answer your own question and accept the answer. It makes it easy for the other readers to know the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by @ScottCraner. To use a named reference in conditional formatting, you have to use `INDIRECT()`

This is the final product: `=(MONTH(INDEX(INDIRECT("Schedule"), MATCH(D1, INDIRECT("Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]]"), 0), 7)) = MONTH( DATEVALUE( D$2 & "1" ) )) * (YEAR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Schedule"), MATCH(D1, INDIRECT("Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]]"), 0), 7)) = $B$3) * (INDEX(INDIRECT("Schedule"), MATCH(D1, INDIRECT("Schedule[[Full Name]:[Full Name]]"), 0), 7)<> "")`